# Get full height of element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My blog has a content `div` with an `id` of `#content`. When I select it, e.g. with Firebug it outlines the full height of the `div`, with all its padding and margins at the top and the bottom.

jQuery `height()` returns only the inner height of the element itself.

How can I query the *full* height of the element? If there are other elements with a lot padding and margin in them I want *all of it* added up and as one value.

Which method should i use?

Answer (score 51):

You can use `outerWidth` and `outerHeight` functions available after `jQuery >= 1.3.`

`$(elemenet).outerHeight()` will return height including height with borders and paddings

use `$(element).outerHeight(true)` to include margins as well.